# Xamarin: Show Spinner Only After Time Threshold, Concurrency Issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm in Xamarin.iOS using BTProgressHUD to show a spinner on the UI. I'd like to show the spinner when the following two conditions are met:

1. A certain amount of time has passed (some threshold, like 50ms)
2. The spinner hasn't already been marked as dismissed.

I'm holding the operation/spinner's state in a custom object:

```
internal class SpinnerInfo, IDisposable
{
    public string Context; // The calling method, for telemetry
    public string UserMessage; // The message to show on the spinner
    public Stopwatch Timer; // To time how long the spinner is on the screen for telemetry
    protected object _stopLock = new object();
    private Timer _delayTimer;

    public SpinnerInfo(string userMessage, string context = "Unknown")
    {
        Context = context;
        UserMessage = userMessage;
        Timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        _delayTimer = new Timer(20); // threshold in ms before showing the spinner
        _delayTimer.Elapsed += AfterDelayHandler;
        _delayTimer.AutoReset = false; // Fire the event one time only
        _delayTimer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        lock (_stopLock)
        {
            Timer.Stop();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When the waiting threshold has been reached, if the task
    /// is still going (i.e. the spinner should still be on the screen)
    /// then actually show the spinner
    /// </summary>
    private void AfterDelayHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (_stopLock)
        {
            if (Timer.IsRunning) // Easy way to see if the operation is still executing
            { // Operation is still in progress
                BTProgressHUD.Show(UserMessage, -1, ProgressHUD.MaskType.Black);
            }
            _delayTimer.Stop();
        }
    }

    // [IDisposable implementation that disposes of the _delayTimer]
    [...]
}
```

When code requests the spinner to show up, it'll create a new SpinnerInfo and add it to a stack. When the code wants the spinner to go away (the long-running operation is complete), it pops it from the stack, `Stop()`s it, and reports the information as telemetry.

However, I'm running into deadlocks on those `lock`s. I added the locks in because I was worried about the following situation:

1. Thread A kicks off an operation and a SpinnerInfo
2. Thread B is fired off by the Timer's `AfterDelayHandler` and checks to see if the spinner's Stopwatch is still running; it is
3. The operation stops and Thread A stops the spinner's Stopwatch
4. Thread B calls BTProgressHUD to show the spinner

The spinner is then on the screen forever.

Is there a better way to coordinate between these two threads to avoid this situation?

Comment: Use `private object _stopLock = new object();` instead of `protected` to have a try.

Comment: @Kevin didn't make a difference